# Testing between levels of random effects in nested models

Tags: anova, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, nested-data

I read a paper recently which was using a nested anova design to investigate differences in fish within rivers. Their response variable was continuous (weight, in grams). There were two categorical predictor variables: Coast (East or West), and River (with 10 different rivers). River was nested within Coast, as 5 rivers only occured on the East Coast, and 5 occured on the West. River was also coded as a random factor.

Two hypotheses were tested. (1): Does weight differ between coasts?, and (2) do the five rivers within each coast differ from each other?

Here's my question. In my (very limited) understanding of random effects, I thought that you could not test for differences between the levels of random effects, and that was partly what differentiated them from fixed effects. If this is true, how were the authors able to test for differences between rivers?

Thanks all

Comment: I think this is hard to answer without reading the original paper (since your question is specifically about the paper). Also, what do you mean with "levels of random effects?". Testing for statistical significance can be done using various tests (such as the t-test which you probably know), a comparison with (sort of) random data could be made using a [permutation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)) for example.

Comment: Sorry, did my best explain it fully, and make it a general statistical question. By 'levels' I just meant that the 'River' variable had 10 different rivers, and I didn't understand how mean differences between rivers were tested if it was a random factor. I thought use of tests like the t-test generally worked off fixed effects